# Crypto key handling in a uC

Tags: microcontroller, memory, data-storage

What are the general guidelines for handling a cryptographic keys?

I know that saving them in plaintext is generally frowned upon, does this hold for true uCs where no user code is run?

Comment: Preferably, inside a key-storage unit that's part of a crypto hardware accelerator peripheral and doesn't permit reading the keys back out through JTAG / whatever debug interface, only using them internally for encryption/decryption/signing functions.  Not all uCs have such a peripheral, but if you're serious about encryption, you'd use one that does.

Comment: What if crypto is done in software?

Comment: Then you should assume it is broken if anyone gets physical access, and focus your efforts on preventing remote access.  The key will always be held in plaintext during operation.

Comment: I think your question is better suited for another stack, the fact that we are speaking of a uC is marginal... I believe there is an sx just for crypto, head there to find the best available advice.